# Split textfield value in 2 parts and put each part in a var

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a textfield, that has a text value: France Paris. Now I need to know how I can take that string, cut it in 2 parts (France and Paris) and put those two parts in a var. So:

```
<textfield id="field1" text="France Paris">
```

and somewhere i should get

```
var1 = France;
var2 = Paris;
```

I know there is a split string command, but I'm not familiar with any of this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use the `split()` method on your String. This will split your String and put the values in an Array. You can use it like this:

```
var yourString:String = "France Paris";
var splitString:Array = yourString.split(" ");

var firstWord:String = splitString[0];  
var secondWord:String = splitString[1];
```

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29)